# Formatting the output from a search

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to make a search feature for my web page but I have difficulties with formatting the outcome so that it comes out in the table format this is my code:

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];      
    $min_length = 10;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aggrement
            WHERE (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`start_date` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`end_date` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`balance` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`tax_value` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`amount_paid` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`hosting_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`domain_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`first_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`last_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['description']."</h3>".$results['start_date']."</p>";
                         }    
        }
        else{
            echo "No results";
        }
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

I'm using echo to output the results  `echo "<p><h3>".$results['description']."</h3>".$results['start_date']."</p>";`

but I want to use this syntax:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=description'>Description</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=start_date'>Start Date</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=end_date'>End Date</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=balance'>Balance</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=tax_value'>Tax </th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=amount_paid'>Amount Paid</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=domain_name'>Domain Name</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=hosting_name'>Hosting Name</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=first_name'>First Name</th>
<th><a href='viewaggrement.php?sort=last_name'>Last Name</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";
echo "<table>";
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?  If you already know the HTML structure that you want to output, why don't you replace your current version with that?  In what way is that not working?

Comment: you don't close the table tag. could that be your problem?

Comment: if i put $results['description'] its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get the results you need:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){
    echo "<table>";
    // echo your header row here
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$results['description']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$results['start_date']."</td>";
        //And so on for each row you require
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

Open the table tag before you start looping through your results and create a row for each result. Then when it is finished looping through your results, close the table tag.

```
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];      
    $min_length = 10;

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aggrement
            WHERE (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`start_date` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`end_date` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`balance` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`tax_value` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`amount_paid` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`hosting_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`domain_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`first_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`last_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){

        echo "<table>";
            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$results['description']."</td><td>".$results['start_date']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                         }    

        echo "</table>";
        }
        else{
            echo "No results";
        }
    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```